# RecyclerView(перемешивает все свои элементы)

Tags: android

У меня есть **Adapter** который заполняет **CardView** 3мя layout'ами(LinerLayout), в свою очередь в них находится **TextView** и **ImageView**. При заполнении списка(когда он уходит за пределы экрана) и его перелистывании элементы которые были выше перемешиваются, в один **LinearLayout** может залезть несколько **TextView**.

```
public class MSGAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MSGAdapter.MSGViewHolder> {

ArrayList<MessageModel> messages;

public MSGAdapter(ArrayList<MessageModel> messages) {
    this.messages = messages;
}

@Override
public MSGViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.msg_card_layout, parent, false);
    MSGAdapter.MSGViewHolder nh = new MSGAdapter.MSGViewHolder(v);
    return nh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MSGViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Context ctx = holder.itemView.getContext();

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparamsFile = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams mLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    LinearLayout mLinerLayout = new LinearLayout(ctx); //Основной контейнер
    mLinerLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    mLinerLayout.setLayoutParams(mLayout);

    LinearLayout linearLayoutTextContent = new LinearLayout(ctx);     //Контейнер для текста сообщения
    linearLayoutTextContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayoutTextContent.setLayoutParams(lparams);

    LinearLayout linearLayoutFileContent = new LinearLayout(ctx);   //Контейнер для вложения
    linearLayoutFileContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearLayoutFileContent.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    linearLayoutFileContent.setPadding(10,10,10,10);


    TextView messageContent = new TextView(ctx);    //Текст сообщения
    messageContent.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    messageContent.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
    messageContent.setText(messages.get(position).getContent().toString()); // Добавление текста сообщения

    if(messages.get(position).getFile() != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.get(position).getFile().size(); i++) {
                ImageView file = new ImageView(ctx);//Изображение вложения
                file.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                file.setLayoutParams(lparamsFile);
                switch (messages.get(position).getFile().get(i).getType().toString()) {
                    case "img":
                        Glide.with(ctx).load(messages.get(position).getFile().get(i).getSrc()).into(file);
                        break;
                    case "doc":
                        file.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.doc));
                        break;
                    case "audio":
                        file.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.audio));
                        break;
                    case "video":
                        file.setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.video));
                        break;
                }

                linearLayoutFileContent.addView(file);
            }

    }
    linearLayoutTextContent.addView(messageContent); //Добавление заполненного контейнера в диалог

    if(messages.get(position).getFile() != null && !(messages.get(position).getContent().equals("null"))) {  // Сообщение и вложение
        mLinerLayout.addView(linearLayoutTextContent);
        mLinerLayout.addView(linearLayoutFileContent);
        holder.cv.addView(mLinerLayout);
    } else if(messages.get(position).getFile() != null && messages.get(position).getContent().equals("null")){ // Вложение
        mLinerLayout.addView(linearLayoutFileContent);
        holder.cv.addView(mLinerLayout);
    } else if(messages.get(position).getFile() == null && !(messages.get(position).getContent().equals("null"))) { // Сообщение
        mLinerLayout.addView(linearLayoutTextContent);
        holder.cv.addView(mLinerLayout);

    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messages.size();
}

public static class MSGViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    CardView cv;

    public MSGViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.msg_card);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно это из-за того что в статическом MSGViewHolder у меня только CardView и Adapter запоминает только его? а остальные элементы он создает по новой а состоянии их не запоминает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно используете адаптер. Все создание элементов должно происходить в `onCreateViewHolder()`. `onBindViewHolder()` получает ссылку на структуру, созданную во время `onCreateViewHolder()` (т.е. все вьюхи уже созданы) и исключительно управляет их видимостью, внешним видом и отображаемыми данными.